# PDF file name not taken into account in IE10 / Edge

Tags: angularjs, pdf, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-edge

Using this code, i have the pdf's name that is incorrect : A string of random letters like a uuid.
This problem seems to only be with IE 10 / Edge.
AngularJS's version 1.4.7

```
this.downloadPdf = function(pdfName){
    console.log(pdfName);
    $http.get(config.UrlApi + "/pdf/"+ pdfName.nameFile, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     a.target = '_blank';
     a.download = pdfName.name;
     document.body.appendChild(a);
     a.click();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Blob Interface:

```
function build(response)
  {
  var bb = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf"});

  if (URL && URL.hasOwnProperty("createObjectURL") )
    {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(bb);
    }
  else if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(bb, 'foo.pdf');
    }
  }

$http.get(config.UrlApi + "/pdf/"+ pdfName.nameFile, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(build);
```

> Blob urls are subject to an origin policy. This means that they can only be used in documents that have the same site-of-origin as the document running the script that created the url. If you need to use the blob object from an `<iframe>` that is running in a different domain, you must use the postMessage API to send the blob data to the frame and then create the blob: url there.

**References**

- [Saving files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016)
- [New Blob Constructor in IE10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/07/20/new-blob-constructor-in-ie10/)
- [Edge Doesn't Use download attribute to set filename for blob URI downloading](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7260192/)
- [Blob Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453178.aspx)
- [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
- [MSDN: JavaScript Version Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz)